# I don't want to be a mod

Tags: script, style

Ever earned the privilege "Access to moderator tools" and not really wanted it?

A stylesheet for hiding deleted answers, as well as the review queue. For use with stylish. Customise to include the sites you do not wish to see moderator-only content on.

```
@-moz-document domain("lifehacks.stackexchange.com") {
.deleted-answer,
.topbar .topbar-links .topbar-menu-links a.icon-flag.icon-tools-flag, .topbar .topbar-links .topbar-menu-links a.icon-flag.icon-tools-flag:visited
{
    display:none;
}
}
```

Comment: Then people will kill you for not doing your duty as a mod